# Spring @Bean method executing after @Autowired

Tags: spring, configuration, controller, javabeans, autowired

I use Spring Boot MVC application.
I have a `@Configuration` class that initializes a bean into `ApplicationContext` using `@Bean`.
I have a `@Controller` class into which I am trying to autowire the bean using `@Autowired` annotation.

Result: `@Autowired` field is `null`.

DEBUG: I tried to debug to see the order of execution.  I was expecting to see that class annotated with `@Configuration` will run first to initialize bean into application context.  However, controller class got instantiated first.  Then `@Bean` method of configuration class got called next.  Due to this bean is instantiated after controller and that is why Controller is not getting bean autowired.

Question: How to have `@Configuration` `@Bean` method execute prior to the controller class instantiation?

---

code for configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class RootConfiguration2 {

    @Autowired
    private IService<ActBinding> bindingService;

    @Bean
    public Map<String, String> getBingindNameToRoutingKeyMap() throws Exception {
        ListOperation<ActBinding> operation = ListOperation.from("key", "name", "exchangeId");
        operation.sort("key", SortOrder.Ascending);
        Iterable<ActBinding> result = bindingService.list(operation).getResult();
        Map<String, String> bindingNameToRoutingKey = new HashMap<>();
        result.forEach(x -> bindingNameToRoutingKey.put(x.getName(), x.getKey()));
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(bindingNameToRoutingKey);
    }
}
```

Comment: could you share the configuration class code?

Comment: Turn on logging and check for warning messages.

Comment: You'd have to show the code for IService<ActBinding> and where you inject getBingindNameToRoutingKeyMap. It could be a circular dependency, though you did not mentioned such error. It could a typo when injection getBingindNameToRoutingKeyMap paired with @Autowring(required=false)... need more code.

Answer (score 4):

I found two workarounds. Both solutions worked:
1. Use @Resource instead of @Autowired to inject the bean into controller.
2. Use @PostConstruct on the method annotated with @Bean in Configuration class.

Note: You dont have to do both of the changes.  Any one of them should work.